# Curl command to POST data flask with extra parameter - unconsumed column

Tags: python, curl, flask, sqlalchemy

How to use curl command syntax to post data other than that on the form. Requirement is during adding a record, I check for a particular value, 
`data = request.get_json(force=True).` If a `particular dict value is None`, then read the argument passed in the curl which is not part of the json model, compute some value and populate the json key with the computed value. I am unable to add the extra dict value with the -d option of curl as:

```
curl -b cookies.txt -X POST http://localhost:5000/api/v1.0/app1 -d '{"description":"Adding obj", "workflow_id":1}' -H 'Content-type:application/json'
```

Here 'workflow_id' is not part of the json model but computes a value 'workflow stage' required to be populated in the table. How exactly should the value 'workflow_id' be passed in curl? If passed as above, it throws error:

> CompileError: Unconsumed column names: workflow_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing it as part of the header. The header can accept custom values and you can access it from from the request headers in the controller.

In this case just add 
`-H 'workflow-id: 1'` to your request

Comment: Thx for quick response :)